# SFML Increasing random falling meteors

Tags: sfml, random

Im working on a small project where i have to creat a 2d game using C++ and SFML (it wasn't my choice to use them)
i did every thing like creating the ship ,shooting ,score counter ..etc
i managed to make like 5 meteors falling in random direction and entering the screen again whenever they leave the window
the only thing that confuses me is making the number of meteors increase during the gameplay ,any tip to help?

Comment: Are you using classes to create the meteors? Or are them just hard-coded in there?

Comment: @user6245072 At first i tried to create them with classes but i couldn't really figure it out so i just chose the dump way and created an array of circle shapes `sf::circleshape met[10]` and then loaded the the meteor texture into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a static size `std::array`, which size can't be changed during the execution, you could use a [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), this will allow you to change the amount of meteor arbitrarily.

And for the increased amount, you don't supply much information about how your code currently works, but...

If you use a fixed time step, you need to have a frame counter at some point where you decide to add a new meteor to the list.

```
// pseudo-code
int mMeteorAddIntervalFrame = 300; // frame
int mMeteorAddAccumulatorFrame = 0; // frame
std::list<sf::sprite> mMetorSprites;

void update():
  ++mMeteorAddAccumulatorFrame
  if mMeteorAddAccumulatorFrame >= mMeteorAddIntervalFrame:
    mMetorSprites.push_back(new sf::sprite) // and initialize the sprite
    mMeteorAddAccumulatorFrame = 0
```

If you use a variable time step, instead of a frame counter, you need a delta-time accumulator: if the time passed is above your desired threshold, add a new meteor to the list, and decrease the accumulator by the time desired:

```
// pseudo-code
double mMeteorAddIntervalMs = 3000; // ms
double mMeteorAddAccumulatorMs = 0; // ms
std::list<sf::sprite> mMetorSprites;

void update(double aDeltaTimeMs):
  mMeteorAddAccumulatorMs += aDeltaTimeMs
  if mMeteorAddAccumulatorMs >= mMeteorAddIntervalMs:
    mMetorSprites.push_back(new sf::sprite) // and initialize the sprite
    mMeteorAddAccumulatorMs -= mMeteorAddIntervalMs // this ensures that it's always 
                                                    // approximately at the desired interval,
                                                    // without losing miliseconds here and 
                                                    // there
```

Comment: i didn't understand every thing you wrote there (i'm a noob) but i got the overall idea
the problem now is i'm stuck at how to move all the meteors at once (old & new) basically i use `met[0].setposition(x0+1,y0+1);` inside the game loop but i can't write the code for the new meteors from the beginning (_before i dynamically allocate them_), is there a better way to do it other than dozen of **If** statements & repeating the code again in each statement ?

Comment: If you use a `std::list`, you can use an iterator. I suggest you [search google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=c%2B%2B+list+iterator+tutorial) about iterators.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt: Using a std::list is not the preferred C++ way. When using collections one should always use std::vector except when there is a real good reason to use something else. std::list has a worse performance than a std::vector, even when adding and deleting many elements. Also raw pointers should be avoided wherever possible. Use smart pointers instead. But since you've wrote pseudo code I hope it's fine. But it's not good to point beginners in the wrong direction. ;)

Comment: @Skalli Please consider the scope of the question. The OP is obviously at an entry level, and the content of the container appears to be quite low. The performances, in this case, are pretty irrelevant. Once they'll know that there is more than one way to store and access data, maybe that's going to be more important. Meanwhile, this is really premature optimization, and we have no way to know how the OP implemented everything else.

Comment: @Skalli _"But since you've wrote pseudo code"_ yes, this is pseudo code. I have no way to know how they uses their data; smart pointers would be indeed the way to go, but this is not in the scope of this question.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt: Using std::vector is not about optimization in this context. It's simply the default data container used in C++. Unless there is no other reason, go with vector. I pointed it out because this is an entry level question and containers are used often wrong or with false assumption when learning C++ or switching from another language like C# or Java. It's not wrong to use std::list, but bad style in this context. Vectors work with iterators fine too. Also access via index works fine too: met[0].setPosition(...);

Comment: @Skalli Your arguments are not that much convincing, but yeah, vector or list, as long as it works :P. You're welcome to suggest an edit to the answer if you feel like it!

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt: When I'm at home I might edit it. Sorry that my point didn't came out as I wanted it. I based my comment on [this article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists) after it was pointed out to me too years ago when I answered a question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty array of circleshapes which is larger than 10 (size = max number of meteors on the screen, for example 25) and just fill its first 10 indexes, and then, as time passes, add more circleshapes to the array until the maximum size is reached.

You may want to keep a variable holding the actual size of the meteors array, but remember to increase it as you add more meteors.